# Character Behavior during addition and subtraction in Java

Tags: java, character, ascii

**Addition**:

System.out.println('3'+'1');

**output**: 52(i believe it is because of ASCII values)

**Subtraction**:

System.out.println('3'-'1');

**output**:2

**Question**: Since it take ASCII value for Addition but why it takes Actual value for Subtraction,can anyone please Help on this?

Comment: Did you even run this code? I pasted the exact two lines you have here and did not get the same output as you.

Comment: May i know what is the output your are getting..?

Comment: @Prasanth2617 it should be exactly the same as what you get.

Comment: The ASCII value is the actual value so I don't understand the difference you are asking about.

Comment: Unfortunately the ASCII value and the actual int value gaves the same the result so i'm confused..!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your guess is correct that for addition it takes ASCII value.
It takes ASCII value for subtraction also.

But **sout('3'+'1')** gives answer = 100. (as ASCII value of 3 is 51 and ASCII value for 1 is 49).

And **sout('3'-'1')** , gives answer=2.

Answer (score 0):

This is consistent. The ASCII value of 3 is 51 and 1 is 49.

Your first expression is therefore `51 + 49 = 100`

And your second one is `51 - 49 = 2`. Funny coincidence the answer is the same as if they were numbers not chars!

**Edit** I see you were getting 52 for the first expression. This is what you would get if you had written `System.out.println('3' + 1);` (no quotes around the second char), as the ASCII 51 + the `int` 1 = 52.

Comment: Thanks a lot..!!! @hughjdavey i haven't noticed, irrespective of number or char they gave the same answer..!!! :) :)

Comment: No problem. Could you upvote and accept the answer if it has answered your question :)

Comment: You can also get 52 from leaving out the quotes around the second char; `3 + '1'` equals 3 + 49 equals 52.

Answer (score 0):

First, `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, UTF-16 being one of several encodings for the Unicode character set.

For the ranges of characters U+0000 to U+D7FF and U+E000 to U+FFFF, UTF-16 encodes them in one code unit (`char`) with values '\u0000' to '\uD7FF' and '\uE000' to '\uFFFF'. So, within those ranges a `char` can be considered a complete character.

Now, within some codepoint ranges, the order is sometimes useful: digits '0' to '9' and Basic Latin letters 'A' to 'Z' and 'a' to 'z' are in the natural order.

So, in those cases, you could use subtraction to determine the "distance" between values. '3' - '1' = 2 means '3' is two beyond '1'.

(It is tempting to apply this logic to letters, too. However, because alphabets vary by language, it is much more direct to use a string to give an ordering to an alphabet, for example, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ".)

The addition of characters isn't something that I can attach a meaning to ('3' + '1'), though it is allowed because `char` can be implicitly or explicitly converted between integers (the UTF-16 code unit value).